# Finding relationship columns in an Entity Framework T4 script

Tags: entity-framework, testing, t4

I'm trying to create a script to generate tests from an entity framework edmx file. I want to ensure columns are all written and relationships are correct.

I can't compare columns that are database keys since these are automatically generated. The database model also includes references from child records to parents. Any suggestions how to detect columns in the child tables that reference parents? (Columns that participate in relationships).

I've figured out how to iterate over the columns, and to exclude the key column for each table:

```
    var sqlColumns = typeMapper.GetSimpleProperties(entity);
    if (sqlColumns.Any())
    {
        foreach (var sqlColumn in sqlColumns)
        {
          if ( ! ef.IsKey(sqlColumn) )
          {
#>
                // test for non relationship columns goes here
<#
          }
        }
    }
```

This version of EF includes the file:

```
<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude"#><#@
```

Comment: `typeMapper.GetNavigationProperties(entity)`?

Comment: I think GetNavigationProperties() shows relations to children not relations from parents. I'll try that

Comment: There is also `typeMapper.GetCollectionNavigationProperties(entity)`

Comment: I double checked and the property that's failing the test is a one to one relationship to another table. It doesn't show up in the NavigationPropertiesCollection or as a key. :(  Thanks for helping.